# List of List of Buttons is empty

Tags: java, list, gwt

I'm working around with GWT.

Since I have a SQL db and my queries result set size is unknown I thought it would make sense to use Lists.

Actually I have one list of buttons and a second list of list of buttons.

The reason is because I have one table which stores groups and one which stores the actual data. Both of them in result should be buttons.

By clicking on a group button my layout is filled with the data buttons between the group buttons.

Now my db connection isn't ready to use so I wrote a function that fills my lists with fake data. Same for the groups.

```
public void fakeGroupData () {
// Group index 0
    btnGroupList.add(new Button("Group a"));
// Group index 1
    btnGroupList.add(new Button("Group b"));
    ...
}

public void fakeData () {

// Group index 0
    btnDataList.add(new Button("Data 1.1"));
    btnDataList.add(new Button("Data 1.2"));
    btnDataList.add(new Button("Data 1.3"));
    btnDataListList.add(btnDataList);
    btnDataList.clear();

// Group index 1
    btnDataList.add(...
}
```

Declaration looks like this

```
List<Button> btnGroupList = new ArrayList<Button>();
List<List<Button>> btnDataListList = new ArrayList<List<Button>>();
List<Button> btnDataList = new ArrayList<Button>();
```

When trying to get the ButtonList of the ListList the error appears.

```
    int grpIndex = Panel.getWidgetIndex(grpBtn);
// grpBtn is equal to (Button)event.getSource() called by btnGroup ClickHandler
    btnDataList.clear()
    btnDataList = btnDataListList.get(grpIndex);
    int loopEnd = btnDataList.size() - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i<=loopEnd; i++) {...
```

"loopEnd" contains "-1" and nothing happens :(. I tried to debug here, everything seems ok.
"grpIndex" has the right index so the the right List is loaded. 
But why is it empty? When debuggin the fakeData function eclipse shows the right size in the ButtonList.

Hope you can help me :)

Comment: Instead of filling with fake data, how about if you do it when you know the database connection is ready? Have a read about multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, observer pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`btnDataList.clear();` will empty your referenced list objects.

for each Group index you need a new list. do like this

`btnDataList = new ArrayList<Button>();` instead of `btnDataList.clear();`

```
// Group index 0
btnDataList.add(new Button("Data 1.1"));
btnDataList.add(new Button("Data 1.2"));
btnDataListList.add(btnDataList);

// Group index 1
btnDataList = new ArrayList<Button>();
btnDataList.add(new Button("Data 2.1"));
btnDataList.add(new Button("Data 2.2"));
btnDataListList.add(btnDataList);
```

Comment: THIS my friend makes very much sense. Now i understood the problem. Executing .clear() on btnDataList also clears the btnDataListList and thats why the size is 0. Thank you very much :) this made me go crazy the last hour!